# Encoding a bytes array with function signature: "TypeError: This type cannot be encoded."

Tags: solidity, bytes, abi.encodewithsignature

I have a function in a smart contract I'm trying to call with `call`.

```js
function doStuff(bytes[] calldata data) external payable {
```

To call it, I'm running:

```js
bytes[] memory dataArray = new bytes[](1);
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = CONTRACT_ADDRESS.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("doStuff(bytes[])", dataArray)
        );
```

But I keep getting:

```
TypeError: This type cannot be encoded.
            abi.encodeWithSignature("doStuff(bytes[])", dataArray)
```

At compile time. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Solidity version are you using?

I'm using Solidity version `0.8.16` and it's working fine for me.

Check:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract DoStuff {

    event DidStuff(uint256 timestamp);

   function doStuff(bytes[] memory _data) public {

        // Doing stuff..

        emit DidStuff(block.timestamp);
    }

}

contract Contract {

    address CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

    constructor(address doStuffAddress) {
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS = doStuffAddress;
    }
    
    function doIt() public {

        bytes[] memory dataArray = new bytes[](1);
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = CONTRACT_ADDRESS.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("doStuff(bytes[])", dataArray)
        );

    }

}
```

Tested from Remix (I'm not sure what you are using):

```
[block:6 txIndex:0]from: 0xE81...4429Eto: Contract.doIt() 0xD8C...97aA9value: 0 weidata: 0xb29...f0835logs: 1hash: 0xb07...8bdeb
status  true Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0x1ed0efca8ae04b6023af938acb6f2ba87dc066708d30bbe45d1884e18470d34d
from    0xE81903819F26C76C33f6f35967A56ca545f4429E
to  Contract.doIt() 0xD8C3fA537fc8FBe442E007759207cdd3AA997aA9
gas 27547 gas
transaction cost    27547 gas 
input   0xb29...f0835
decoded input   {}
decoded output   - 
logs    [
    {
        "from": "0xB5c6870320fEDcE225116588aD29dc4cCd988770",
        "topic": "0x492037fdabb4ac5a9b4e72edb0de0d83013611c4a53b457573d0d085f9222296",
        "event": "DidStuff",
        "args": {
            "0": "1665669544",
            "timestamp": "1665669544"
        }
    }
]
val 0 wei
```

Comment: 0.7.6. I see... Looks like they updated. Wonder what version this fails on. Thanks!